# DataTable based type returns 0 rows during WCF call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

My WCF service works with svcutil generated type (based on table columns) that looks like:

```
     ///Represents the strongly named DataTable class.
            ///</summary>
            [global::System.Serializable()]
            [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")]
            public partial class tblQPlanInteractionsDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<tblQPlanInteractionsRow> {

                private global::System.Data.DataColumn columniInteractionID;
                ...
public tblQPlanInteractionsDataTable() {
                this.TableName = "tblQPlanInteractions";
                this.BeginInit();
                this.InitClass();
                this.EndInit();
            }
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
            [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
            public tblQPlanInteractionsRow AddtblQPlanInteractionsRow(
                        long iInteractionID, 
...
```

It is used in the method below:

```
[OperationContract]
        BaseQualityPlanInteractions.tblQPlanInteractionsDataTable GetInteractionById(string loginToken, LongIdWithSite interactionId);
```

But client every time receives 0 rows even if server side contains some data.

Target framework of client - .NET 4.6

Server .NET 3.5

Comment: Net 3.5 in using 32 bit integers while Net 4.6 is using 64 bit integers which may have something to do with the issue.  You are using LongIdWithSite.

Comment: I don't see the problem with LongIdWithSite because it is transferred to server OK and data is found as expected but moving data in back direction is problematic. But in general it is a good idea - I'll try change framework version for server side (to be the same) and test

Comment: If the server has the class property size as an int 64 and the client has the size an int 32 will will have an issue.

Comment: this might due to the serialization issue with the Dataset in the older Dotnet framework version.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/xml-and-ado-net-types-in-data-contracts